# Skip file in VBA copy paste

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste

I have a VBA code that copies data from MS Word documents in a folder and pastes them into an MS Excel file. The folder contains about over 2000 MS word files. The code opens each word file in the folder and looks for two key words, lets call them "FindWord1" and "FindWord2", then copies all the data (including text) that is located between these two keywords from this word file and pastes it into a Excel worksheet. Then moves on to the next Word file in the folder.

Some of these 2000 word documents are missing the two keywords. If the code does not find the key words (either "Findword1" or "Findword2") it returns an error. So only the word documents opened before this error are copied and pasted. Is there a way to log the files names of the word documents that are missing the keywords, skip them and move on to the next file in the folder.

The code runs fine as is, but I have to manually go and remove the file from the folder for it to go to the next file which is taking a lot of time. I would appreciate any help here.

Thanks,

N

```
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model. See under the VBE's Tools|References.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Objects
    Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, lRow As Long
    Dim WkSht As Worksheet: Set WkSht = ActiveSheet

'Folder Location
    strFolder = "C:\Users\Folder\"
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.docx", vbNormal)
    
'Loop Start

    While strFile <> ""
      Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
      lRow = WkSht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
      With wdDoc
      
      ' Text you want to search
        Dim FindWord1, FindWord2 As String
        Dim result As String
        FindWord1 = "Keyword1"
        FindWord2 = "Keyword2"
        
        'Style
        mystyle = ""
      
    'Defines selection for Word's find function
        wdDoc.SelectAllEditableRanges
    
    ' Move your cursor to the start of the document
        wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory

    'Find Functionality in MS Word
     With wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
        .Text = FindWord1
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        If mystyle <> "" Then
        .Style = mystyle
        End If
             If .Execute = False Then
            MsgBox "'Text' not found.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Locate after the ending paragraph mark (beginning of the next paragraph)
        ' wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        
        ' Starting character position of a selection
        lngStart = wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.End 'Set Selection.Start to include searched word
        .Text = FindWord2
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        '.Style = mystyle
        If .Execute = False Then
            MsgBox "'Text2' not found.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        lngEnd = wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Start 'Set Selection.End to include searched word
    End With
    
  'Copy Selection
   wdDoc.Range(lngStart, lngEnd).Copy
        WkSht.Paste WkSht.Range("C" & lRow)
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
      End With
      
    strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    
    wdApp.Quit
    
    Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please remember to declare all variables, add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to help you enforce this.
2. You might know this already but `Dim FindWord1, FindWord2 As String` will declare `FindWord1` as Variant, you have to declare the variable type for each variable one by one i.e. `Dim FindWord1 As String, FindWord2 As String`.
3. What is `mysetyle` for? It's not being used but I have left it there anyway, please delete if there is no use for it.

Try below code, if the Word document does not contain both keywords then it will prompt a `MsgBox` and `Debug.Print` to the immediate window, modify to your needs:

```
Private Sub Test()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model. See under the VBE's Tools|References.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Objects
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim WkSht As Worksheet
    Set WkSht = ActiveSheet
    Const colPaste As Long = 3 'Column C
'Search String
    Const FindWord1 As String = "Keyword1"
    Const FindWord2 As String = "Keyword2"
    
'Folder Location
    'Const strFolder As String = "C:\Users\Folder\"
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.docx", vbNormal)
    
'Loop Start
    While strFile <> vbNullString
        If wdApp Is Nothing Then Set wdApp = New Word.Application
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
              
        lRow = WkSht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
                                
        'Style
        mystyle = vbNullString
                  
        Dim firstRng As Word.Range
        Set firstRng = wdDoc.Range.Duplicate
      
        'Find Functionality in MS Word
        With firstRng.Find
            .Text = FindWord1
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
                        
            .Execute
        End With
        
        If firstRng.Find.Found Then
            Dim secondRng As Word.Range
            Set secondRng = wdDoc.Range(firstRng.End, wdDoc.Range.End).Duplicate
            
            With secondRng.Find
                .Text = FindWord2
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = 1
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                
                .Execute
            End With
            
            If secondRng.Find.Found Then
                'Found both keywords, copy to worksheet
                
                Dim copyRng As Word.Range
                Set copyRng = wdDoc.Range(firstRng.Start, secondRng.End).Duplicate
                
                copyRng.Copy
                'WkSht.Cells(lRow, colPaste).Paste
                WkSht.Paste WkSht.Range("C" & lRow)
            Else
                'Error - second word not found~ abort and move on to next file
                  
                MsgBox "Second word not found" & vbNewLine & _
                strFolder & strFile
                Debug.Print "Second word not found: " & strFolder & strFile
            End If
        Else
            'Error - first word not found~ abort and move on to next file
              
            MsgBox "First word not found" & vbNewLine & _
            strFolder & strFile
            Debug.Print "First word not found: " & strFolder & strFile
        End If
                                                                                   
        Set firstRng = Nothing
        Set secondRng = Nothing
        Set copyRng = Nothing
        
        wdDoc.Close 0
        
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    
    wdApp.Quit
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Set WkSht = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Raymond! Testing it now. Appreciate your help a lot!!

Comment: Hi Raymond, this worked. Thanks a lot for your help. Have a great week.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have lngStart and lngEnd defined somewhere? Maybe `Dim` them and assign 0 to both right after opening the next word doc, and then check if they are not equal to
0 before the copy to excel part. Don't have any considerable experience for Word VBA, sorry if not applicable.

Comment: Hi Gokhan, I was able to use Raymond's advice above that suggested declaring the keywords as dims. Thank you for your response and suggestion. I appreciate it.